# How to insert record into a sql server express database table?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-express, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to insert a textbox value to a database table called `site_list`.

The `site_list` table contains two columns `id` and `site_name`, `id` set to auto increment

This is the code I'm trying and when it execute there is no error, but the data is not showing up in the table

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =
             "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;" +
             "User Instance=true;" +
             "Integrated Security=true;" +
             "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|scraper_db.mdf;";            

SqlCommand addSite = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO site_list (site_name) "
     + " VALUES (@site_name)", conn);

addSite.Parameters.Add("@site_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;

conn.Open();
addSite.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

**Edit:**

This code started to work

```
    string connstring = "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;"+
                        "Integrated Security=true;"+
                        "User Instance=true;"+
                        "AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|scraper_db.mdf;"+
                        "Initial Catalog=scraper_db";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand addSite = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO site_list (site_name)"+
                             "VALUES (@site_name)", connection);
        addSite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@site_name", textBox1.Text); 
        addSite.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You're using the `User Instance / AttachDbFilename=` approach - which I personally find quite messy and confusing at times. Have you tried to run you code, put a breakpoint on the `conn.Close()` and when your code stops there, go check the database file in your data directory with e.g. SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express?? The user instance stuff tends to copy around MDF files and thus your insert may have happened just fine - but when you look at it, you're looking at an old version of the database (without your inserts)

Comment: thanks for the information, what is the best approach to do insert update delete actions with sql server express?

Comment: Wrap your code in a Try Catch for starters.. also change the addSite.Parameter(.....) to addSite.Parameters.AddWIthValue("@site_name", textBox1.Text); Parameters.Add has been depricated..

Comment: I would always create the database **on the server** (in e.g. SQL Server Management Studio Express) and then connect to it using its **logical** database name (don't fiddle around with the physical database files - .mdf and .ldf - leave that to the server.....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as people suggests, try creating the database on the server (it will be even easier to handle using [Sql Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8961)).
Once that's done, try the following (just tested and it works):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=myTestDb;server=(local)"))
{
    SqlCommand addSite = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO site_list (site_name) VALUES (@site_name)", conn);
    addSite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@site_name", "mywebsitename");
    addSite.Connection.Open();
    addSite.ExecuteNonQuery();
    addSite.Connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=myTestDb;server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;database=Inventory;Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;"))
    {
        SqlCommand addSite = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Creation (Name,Product,Quantity,Category) VALUES (@Name,@Product,@Quantity,@Category)", conn);
        addSite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
        addSite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", textBox2.Text);
        addSite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", textBox3.Text.ToString());
        addSite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", textBox4.Text);
        thisConnection.Open();
        addSite.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch
{
    thisConnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this out :

```
string sql = String.Format("INSERT INTO site_list (site_name) VALUES('{0}')", myTextBox.Text);
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
   connection.open();
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
   {
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try storing your textbox value in a variable.  As in:

```
@stringname = textbox1.text
addSite.Parameters.Add("@site_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = @stringname;
```

(IMPORTANT! the @ in @stringname is not necessary, but protects you against hackers!)

This code has worked wonders for me.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies.  The answer I gave previously will not work because the variable name used in the insert command (in your case @site_name) must match the variables used in your sqlcommand.  As in:

```
@site_name = textbox1.text
addSite.Parameters.Add("@site_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
```

Sorry for the confusion I might have caused.