# inserting textbox value to sql server using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add a text box value to SQL Server database table. Below is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\timetablesystem.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    string qry = "insert into SubjectMaster (SubjectName) values (@TxtSubjectName)";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtSubjectName", TxtSubjectName.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully!!");
    con.Close();
}
```

But, data should not add in table... please help me...
thanks for ur help...

Comment: Do you have the file `timetablesystem.mdf` listed between your project files and its property `Copy to output directory` set to `Copy always` ?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your query first, before putting it into code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363061/how-to-insert-record-into-a-sql-server-express-database-table

Comment: `But, data should not add in table` - are you saying that the data ***isn't*** getting added to the table? ***If so,*** how are you verifying that?

Comment: Is there an error when you run your code, use a Try/Catch Statement and grab any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your query first if it works i think your connection with your db isnt working.

```
string str = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\timetablesystem.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

is there supposed to be this '.' after data source `Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS`

Answer (score 0):

try this and tell me what is the message information content

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    using( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str)){
                            try{
                                con.Open();
                                string qry = "insert into SubjectMaster (SubjectName) values (@TxtSubjectName)";
                                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtSubjectName", TxtSubjectName.Text);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully!!");
                               }
                          catch{
                                MessageBox.Show("connection is failed!!");
                               }
                                                       }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SL-20\SQLEXPRESS;Initial   Catalog=TestDB;User ID=sa;Password=sl123;");
        string query = " insert into name(name)values('" + TextboxTest.Text + "')";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```